# The MAPI call 'OpenMsgStore' failed: The MAPI provider failed Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

Recently we moved our Exchange 2003 (SP2) database from one drive to another. Now every other day or so we get errors coming up in the event log:

> Event Type: Error
>   Event Source: MSExchangeSA
>   Event Category: MAPI Session
>   Event ID: 9175
>   Date:  10/03/2010
>   Time:  8:06:15 a.m.
>   User:  N/A
>   Computer: SERVER
>   Description:
>   The MAPI call 'OpenMsgStore' failed with the following error:
>   The attempt to log on to the Microsoft Exchange Server computer has failed.
>   The MAPI provider failed.
>   Microsoft Exchange Server Information Store
>   ID no: 8004011d-0512-00000000

For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

Restarting the Exchange Information Store fixes this instantly, but until we do it Outlook won't connect to Exchange and Blackberry emails aren't pushing out.

Comment: How did you move the mailbox store? Is the System Attendant mailbox present and connected?

Comment: Right clicked on the Mailbox Store and selected the new location then waited for it to move it.

The System Attendant mailbox is connected.

Comment: Do you have any System Policies that may be referencing the old Mailbox Store location?